# How to share Entity Framework between two applications?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have four VS projects in the same solution with the following architecture:

- Admin Application -> Service -> Repository
- Final User Application -> Service - Repository

`Admin` and `User` project share the same layers `Service` / `Repository` but each one has its own server (`user.domain.com` and `admin.domain.com`) so they are in different IIS pools.

I publish them separately, however, when I make some change in admin it does not take any effect in the final user's app due the Entity Framework caching. My repository uses a static context, I cannot lose the entities changes so I cannot turn it into a local context.

I tried this in user's app:

```
foreach (var entity in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
     entity.Reload();
}
```

worked but the application got too slow.

Is there a good way to identify database changes using the same EF layer in two different applications?

Or disable only `User`'s app caching..

I am using EF6 and .NET 4.6.1

Thanks

Comment: "I cannot lose the entities changes so I cannot turn it into a local context." What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My repository uses a static context

Don't do that.  The context should be transient, or scoped to the HTTP request.